# Djangosaml2 configuration

Tags: django, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

Please help me for saml configuration for the OneLogin IdP with djangosml2 library(djangosaml2==0.14.5).

Once i come back on my app after successfully login it fails to parse xml response.

I'm getting error "SAML response has errors. Please check the logs"

Here is my configuration:-

```
SAML_CONFIG = {
  'xmlsec_binary': '/usr/bin/xmlsec1',
  'entityid': 'http://localhost:8006/saml2/metadata/',
  'service': {
      'sp' : {
          'name': 'Federated Django sample SP',
          'allow_unsolicited': True,
          'endpoints': {
              'assertion_consumer_service': [
                  ('http://localhost:8006/saml2/acs/',
                   saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                  ],
              'single_logout_service': [
                  ('http://localhost:8006/saml2/ls/',
                   saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                  ('http://localhost:8006/saml2/ls/post',
                   saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                  ],
              },
          'required_attributes': ['uid'],
          'optional_attributes': ['eduPersonAffiliation'],
          'idp': {
              'https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/595757': {
                  'single_sign_on_service': {
                      saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT: 'https://isystango16.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/595757',
                      },
                  'single_logout_service': {
                      saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT: 'https://isystango16.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/595757',
                      },
                  },
              },
          },
      },
  'metadata': {
      'local': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'new_onelogin_metadata.xml')],
      },
  'debug': 1,
  'cert_file': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'new_onelogin .pem'),
  'contact_person': [
      {'given_name': 'Lorenzo',
       'sur_name': 'Gil',
       'company': 'Yaco Sistemas',
       'email_address': 'lgs@yaco.es',
       'contact_type': 'technical'},
      {'given_name': 'Angel',
       'sur_name': 'Fernandez',
       'company': 'Yaco Sistemas',
       'email_address': 'angel@yaco.es',
       'contact_type': 'administrative'},
      ],
  'organization': {
      'name': [('Yaco Sistemas', 'es'), ('Yaco Systems', 'en')],
      'display_name': [('Yaco', 'es'), ('Yaco', 'en')],
      'url': [('http://www.yaco.es', 'es'), ('http://www.yaco.com', 'en')],
      },
  'valid_for': 24,
  }
```

Comment: And what error appears on logs?

Answer (score 0):

I've has similar problems in the past.  If I remember correctly, the message "SAML response has errors. Please check the logs" doesn't mean the SP found something wrong with the response, it means the IDP is telling you something is wrong.  IE for some reason, the IDP is unhappy and letting you know.  If my memory is telling me the truth, I had this error when the SP and IDP couldn't agree on attribute names... maybe?  The SP was putting a friendlyname in the name property for the attributes it was requesting... or something like that.

Anyway, doubt this helps you since this was 6 months ago, but it might help someone in the future.